# RadioListTile options displayed vertically instead of horizontally (Flutter)

Tags: flutter

I'm facing an issue with Flutter's RadioListTile where the options are displayed vertically instead of horizontally.

I have a list of options ["New Connection", "Upgrade", "Others"], and I want to display RadioListTile for each option horizontally.
I've wrapped the RadioListTile widgets inside a Row widget, but the options are still displayed vertically.

```
return Row(
      children: widget.options.map((option) {
        return SizedBox(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.075,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.3,
          child: RadioListTile<String>(
            title: Text(option),
            value: option,
            groupValue: _selectedOption,
            onChanged: (String? value) {
              setState(() {
                _selectedOption = value!;
                if (widget.onChanged != null) {
                  widget.onChanged!(value);
                }
              });
            },
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 2),
          ),
        );
      }).toList(),
    );




Container(
       width: screenWidth,
       child: Wrap(
          alignment: WrapAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.start,
          direction: Axis.horizontal,
          children: [
             for (String option in ['New Connection', 'Upgrade', 'Others'])
                 RadioListTile(
                     title: Text(option),
                     value: option,
                     groupValue: fieldOptions,
                     onChanged: (String? value) {
                     setState(() {
                         fieldOptions = value!;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
```

Comment: The above code using `Row` works just fine.

Below, I see you are using a `Wrap` widget, and no `width` is set for `RadioListTile`. Then the width will be stretched to the parent for sure. 

But I wonder why are you trying to achieve a horizontal `RadioListTile` with label? It's gonna be a very bad UI/UX.

Answer (score 0):

The above code using `Row` works just fine. But the UI looks quite bad.
[image]

I recommend redesigning the UI for something more user-friendly. Like a `Chip` or `Card` with a highlight color for select things.

Something like this should be more user-friendly
[image: Something like this should be more user-friendly]

```
Row(
      children: ['New Connection', 'Upgrade', 'Others'].map((option) {
        final isSelected = _selectedOption == option;
        return Expanded(
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _selectedOption = option;
                    });
                  },
                  child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: isSelected ? Colors.blue : Colors.white,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                              boxShadow: const [
                                BoxShadow(
                                    color: Color.fromRGBO(12, 26, 75, 0.30),
                                    blurRadius: 4,
                                    offset: Offset(0.0, 2.0)),
                              ]),
                          child: SizedBox(
                            height: 36,
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                option,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: isSelected ? Colors.white : Colors.black
                                ),
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
                      )
                  ),
                ),
                Visibility(
                    visible: isSelected,
                    child: Positioned(
                        right: 6,
                        top: 4,
                        child: Container(
                          clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color:Colors.green,
                              shape: BoxShape.circle
                          ),
                          child: Icon(Icons.check_circle_rounded, color: Colors.white, size: 16),
                        )
                    )
                )
              ],
            )
        );
      }).toList(),
    )
```